# Keep publishing data via publisher RabbitMQ (ruby bunny)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, daemons, bunny

I have a RabbitMQ with bunny working using consumer.rb and publisher.rb. If I run

```
    ruby consumer.rb
```

and then

```
    publisher.rb
```

I get data being published (data coming from another class). Data prints like this on ruby consumer.rb when I run publisher.rb:

```
Test New Data
1142.5186392493372
```

I need these two scripts run constantly so publisher keep pushing the data (@devise.value) through and i see the above output continuously. I have tried making a new server file using Daemon and run ruby server.rb start. But this does keep running publisher.rb but not constantly so it publishes the data. Also how can I make this RabbitMQ ruby app publish data to another web based rails app?

publisher.rb

require 'bunny'
require 'daemons'

class BunnyPublisher

```
def connection
    conn = Bunny.new
    conn.start
end 

def channel
    connection.create_channel
end

def q
    channel.queue("que")
end

def exchange
    channel.default_exchange
end

def publish(data, q)
    exchange.publish(data, routing_key: "que") 

    sleep(5)

    connection.close
end
```

server.rb

```
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run('publisher.rb')
```

Thanks

Comment: Right, I added a while loop to make publisher go on until stopped.                                                      i = 0
    while i < 1
        data = { json format }
        message = data.to_json;
        exchange.publish(message, routing_key: "q", persistent: true)
        sleep(0.5)
   end

Comment: Is the problem solved then?
Maybe update your question to let us know if there are other things you would like help with :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for Deamons. I changed Publisher class code in the original question to the current one. And I added a while loop as mentioned.

ruby file running publisher:

```
i = 0
while i < 1
data = { 
            weight: @devise.value, 
            pressure: @devise.value
        }
    m = data.to_json;
    @pub.publish(m, routing_key: @q) // @pub: Publisher class
end
```

in Publisher class:

```
def publish(data, q)
    exchange.publish(data, routing_key: "queue_name") //exchange another method

    sleep(5) //Publish every 5 seconds

    connection.close
end
```